# AutoLink for Android Compose Text

Tags: android, textview, android-jetpack-compose

Is there any way to use *android:autoLink* feature on JetPack Compose Text?

I know, that it is maybe not "declarative way" for using this feature in one simple tag/modifier, but maybe there is some easy way for this?

For styling text I can use this way

```
 val apiString = AnnotatedString.Builder("API provided by")
        apiString.pushStyle(
            style = SpanStyle(
                color = Color.Companion.Blue,
                textDecoration = TextDecoration.Underline
            )
        )
        apiString.append("https://example.com")

        Text(text = apiString.toAnnotatedString())
```

But, how can I manage clicks here? And would be great, if I programatically say what behaviour I expect from the system (email, phone, web, etc). Like it. works with TextView.
Thank you

Comment: I opened a feature request on the Jetpack Compose issue tracker if you'd like to see Compose support this directly - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/205183601.

Comment: did u get the correct solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can achieve [Linkify](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify) kind of `TextView` in Android Compose like this example below,

```
@Composable
fun LinkifySample() {
    val uriHandler = UriHandlerAmbient.current

    val layoutResult = remember {
        mutableStateOf<TextLayoutResult?>(null)
    }

    val text = "API provided by"
    val annotatedString = annotatedString {
        pushStyle(
            style = SpanStyle(
                color = Color.Companion.Blue,
                textDecoration = TextDecoration.Underline
            )
        )
        append(text)
        addStringAnnotation(
            tag = "URL",
            annotation = "https://example.com",
            start = 0,
            end = text.length
        )
    }
    Text(
        fontSize = 16.sp,
        text = annotatedString, modifier = Modifier.tapGestureFilter { offsetPosition ->
            layoutResult.value?.let {
                val position = it.getOffsetForPosition(offsetPosition)
                annotatedString.getStringAnnotations(position, position).firstOrNull()
                    ?.let { result ->
                        if (result.tag == "URL") {
                            uriHandler.openUri(result.item)
                        }
                    }
            }
        },
        onTextLayout = { layoutResult.value = it }
    )
}
```

In the above example, we can see we give the text and also we use `addStringAnnotation` to set the tag. And using  `tapGestureFilter`, we can get the clicked annotation.

Finally using `UriHandlerAmbient.current` we can open the link like email, phone, or web.

Reference : https://www.hellsoft.se/rendering-markdown-with-jetpack-compose/

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it works fine with URL. But it doesn't work with emails and phone. 
But for these cases, we can use deepLink such as mailto:example@email.com
So, yeah! Thank you! :)

Comment: More up to date solution here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65656351/2633359

Answer (score 2):

The most important part of jetpack compose is the compatibility with native android components.

Create a component that use TextView and use it:

```
@Composable
fun DefaultLinkifyText(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, text: String?) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val customLinkifyTextView = remember {
       TextView(context)
    }
    AndroidView(modifier = modifier, factory = { customLinkifyTextView }) { textView ->
        textView.text = text ?: ""
        LinkifyCompat.addLinks(textView, Linkify.ALL)
        Linkify.addLinks(textView, Patterns.PHONE,"tel:",
            Linkify.sPhoneNumberMatchFilter, Linkify.sPhoneNumberTransformFilter)
        textView.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
    }
}
```

How to use:

```
 DefaultLinkifyText(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .wrapContentHeight(),
    text = "6999999 and https://stackoverflow.com/ works fine"
 )
```