# Normal text with clickable text (not hyper link)

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

I feel that there is a better way to do this thing, I know that this code works, but I just want to know if there is another (best) way to do this.

[image]

```
Row() {

    Text(text = "By signing up, you agree with the ")
    Text(
        text = "Terms of Service",
        modifier = Modifier.clickable { },
        color = Color.Blue
    )
}

Row(
modifier = Modifier.offset(y = (-20).dp)
){

    Text(text = "and ")
    Text(
        text = "Privacy Policy",
        modifier = Modifier
            .clickable { },
        color = Color.Blue
    )
}
```

Comment: Not really a compose user but I would use buildAnnotatedString (https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/text)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65656351/7248394 please check this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `AnnotatedString` and  the `UriHandler` to open the url.

Something like:

```
val annotatedString = buildAnnotatedString {
    append("By signing up, you agree with the ")

    pushStringAnnotation(tag = "terms", annotation = "https://....")
    withStyle(style = SpanStyle(color = Blue)) {
        append("Terms of Service")
    }
    pop()

    append(" and ")

    pushStringAnnotation(tag = "policy", annotation = "https://....")
    withStyle(style = SpanStyle(color = Blue)) {
        append("Privacy Policy")
    }
    pop()

}
val uriHandler = LocalUriHandler.current

ClickableText(
    text = annotatedString,
    onClick = { offset ->
        annotatedString.getStringAnnotations(tag = "terms", start = offset, end = offset).firstOrNull()?.let {
            uriHandler.openUri(it.item)
        }
        annotatedString.getStringAnnotations(tag = "policy", start = offset, end = offset).firstOrNull()?.let {
            uriHandler.openUri(it.item)
        }
})
```

[image]

Comment: what is `pop()` ?

Comment: @vivekmodi you can check the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/AnnotatedString.Builder#pop(kotlin.Int)) Ends the styles or annotation up to and including the pushStyle or pushStringAnnotation that returned the given index.

Comment: Thank you. @GabrieleMariotti. Can you please help me on this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73789740/11560810)