# Text hyperlink hashtags(#) and mentions(@) in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

Text hyperlink hashtags(#) and mentions(@) in Jetpack Compose?

```kotlin
@Composable
fun HashtagsAndMentions() {

    val colorScheme = MaterialTheme.colorScheme
    val primaryStyle = SpanStyle(color = colorScheme.primary)
    val textStyle = SpanStyle(color = colorScheme.onBackground)

    val annotatedString = buildAnnotatedString {

        withStyle(style = textStyle) {
            append("I am ")
        }

        pushStringAnnotation(tag = "hashtags", annotation = "hashtags")
        withStyle(style = primaryStyle) {
            append(text = "#hashtags")
        }
        pop()

        withStyle(style = textStyle) {
            append(" and ")
        }

        pushStringAnnotation(tag = "mentions", annotation = "mentions")
        withStyle(style = primaryStyle) {
            append(text = "@mentions")
        }
        pop()

        withStyle(style = textStyle) {
            append(" in Jetpack Compose.")
        }
    }

    ClickableText(
        onClick = {
            annotatedString.getStringAnnotations("hashtags", it, it).firstOrNull()?.let {

            }
            annotatedString.getStringAnnotations("mentions", it, it).firstOrNull()?.let {

            }
        },
        text = annotatedString,
        style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyLarge,
        modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp))
}
```

```kotlin
@Preview
@Composable
fun PreviewTest() {
    HashtagsAndMentions()
}
```

The above are fixed tags, how to dynamically identify and link?

ideas String to array

```kotlin
val string = "I am #hashtags and @mentions in Jetpack Compose."

val array = arrayOf("I am ", "#hashtags", " and ", "@mentions", "in Jetpack Compose.")
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an available hashtag and mention link.

Many thanks to @cyberpunk_unicorn for the idea, unfortunately his answer is not available, but I marked it anyway.

I refactored his code to ensure that it is runnable, concise enough, and very helpful to those who need it later.

This is a very flexible link scheme, you can add support for mobile phone numbers, emails, links, etc., as long as your regular expressions are correct, these links can be correctly identified.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun HashtagsMentionsTextView(text: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier, onClick: (String) -> Unit) {

    val colorScheme = MaterialTheme.colorScheme
    val textStyle = SpanStyle(color = colorScheme.onBackground)
    val primaryStyle = SpanStyle(color = colorScheme.blue)

    val hashtags = Regex("((?=[^\\w!])[#@][\\u4e00-\\u9fa5\\w]+)")

    val annotatedStringList = remember {

        var lastIndex = 0
        val annotatedStringList = mutableStateListOf<AnnotatedString.Range<String>>()

        // Add a text range for hashtags
        for (match in hashtags.findAll(text)) {

            val start = match.range.first
            val end = match.range.last + 1
            val string = text.substring(start, end)

            if (start > lastIndex) {
                annotatedStringList.add(
                    AnnotatedString.Range(
                        text.substring(lastIndex, start),
                        lastIndex,
                        start,
                        "text"
                    )
                )
            }
            annotatedStringList.add(
                AnnotatedString.Range(string, start, end, "link")
            )
            lastIndex = end
        }

        // Add remaining text
        if (lastIndex < text.length) {
            annotatedStringList.add(
                AnnotatedString.Range(
                    text.substring(lastIndex, text.length),
                    lastIndex,
                    text.length,
                    "text"
                )
            )
        }
        annotatedStringList
    }

    // Build an annotated string
    val annotatedString = buildAnnotatedString {
        annotatedStringList.forEach {
            if (it.tag == "link") {
                pushStringAnnotation(tag = it.tag, annotation = it.item)
                withStyle(style = primaryStyle) { append(it.item) }
                pop()
            } else {
                withStyle(style = textStyle) { append(it.item) }
            }
        }
    }

    ClickableText(
        text = annotatedString,
        style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyLarge,
        modifier = modifier,
        onClick = { position ->
            val annotatedStringRange =
                annotatedStringList.first { it.start < position && position < it.end }
            if (annotatedStringRange.tag == "link") onClick(annotatedStringRange.item)
        }
    )
}
```

```kotlin
@Preview
@Composable
fun PreviewTest() {

    val string = "I am #hashtags or #hashtags# and @mentions in Jetpack Compose. I am #hashtags or #hashtags# and @mentions in Jetpack Compose. 这是在 Jetpack Compose 中的一个 #标签 和 @提及 的超链接。 这是在 Jetpack Compose 中的一个 #标签 和 @提及 的超链接。"

    HashtagsMentionsTextView(string, Modifier.padding(16.dp)) {
        println(it)
    }
}
```

preview effect

[image]