# How to make clickabletext work while accessibility is on for mutiple links in android compose?

Tags: android, text, android-jetpack-compose, talkback

[image: whatsapp terms and condition text]

How to implement multiple substring clickable work in one sentence. and that should work while talkback accessibility is on. like whatsapp. how to achieve this.

Comment: You can try from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65656351/8266651).

Comment: Does this help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/69636806/9636037

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jetpack Compose Text hyperlink some section of the text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65567412/jetpack-compose-text-hyperlink-some-section-of-the-text)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UrlAnnotation` class:

> An annotation that contains the metadata intended for text-to-speech engine. If the text is being processed by a text-to-speech engine, the engine may use the data in this annotation in addition to or instead of its associated text.

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/UrlAnnotation

Here is an example:

```kotlin
val annotatedString = buildAnnotatedString {
    append("This is a ")
    withAnnotation(UrlAnnotation("my_url")) {
        append("clickable")
    }
    append(" text")
}
ClickableText(
    text = annotatedString,
    onClick = { offset ->
        val clickedUrl = annotatedString.getUrlAnnotations(offset, offset)
            .firstOrNull()?.item?.url
        if (clickedUrl == "my_url") {
            TODO("handle click")
        }
    },
)
```

Comment: The way TalkBack handles this is a bit clunky, but using the UrlAnnotation as suggested here is the best solution I've come across so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can used the predefined Composable **ClickableText**.

Below an example of what you want to achieve. Also you can improve the code by defining a data class that will handle the clickable Link properties.

```
@Composable
fun TestScreen() {
    Scaffold { paddingValues ->
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize(1f)
                .padding(paddingValues),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            val firstLink = "Privacy policy"
            val secondLink = "Terms of Service"
            val str = "Read our $firstLink. Tap 'Agree and continue' to accept $secondLink"

            val startIndexOfFirstLink = str.indexOf(firstLink)
            val endIndexOfFirstLink = startIndexOfFirstLink + firstLink.length

            val startIndexOfSecondLink = str.indexOf(secondLink)
            val endIndexOfSecondLink = startIndexOfSecondLink + secondLink.length

            val annotatedString = buildAnnotatedString {
                append(str)
                addStringAnnotation(
                    tag = "policy",
                    annotation = "https://www.whatsapp.com/legal/privacy-policy",
                    start = startIndexOfFirstLink,
                    end = endIndexOfFirstLink
                )
                addStyle(
                    style = SpanStyle(
                        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary
                    ),
                    start = startIndexOfFirstLink,
                    end = endIndexOfFirstLink
                )
                addStringAnnotation(
                    tag = "terms",
                    annotation = "https://www.whatsapp.com/legal/terms-of-service",
                    start = startIndexOfSecondLink,
                    end = endIndexOfSecondLink
                )
                addStyle(
                    style = SpanStyle(
                        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary
                    ),
                    start = startIndexOfSecondLink,
                    end = endIndexOfSecondLink
                )
            }
            ClickableText(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
                text = annotatedString,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium.copy(textAlign = TextAlign.Center),
                onClick = { offset ->
                    val policy = annotatedString.getStringAnnotations(
                        tag = "policy",
                        start = offset,
                        end = offset
                    )
                    if (policy.isNotEmpty()) {
                        /**
                         * open URI in a browser.
                         */
                        Log.e("policy url", policy.first().item)
                    }

                    val terms = annotatedString.getStringAnnotations(
                        tag = "terms",
                        start = offset,
                        end = offset
                    )
                    if (terms.isNotEmpty()) {
                        /**
                         * open browser
                         */
                        Log.e("terms url", terms.first().item)
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this solution works normally but not with accessibility talkback on.

Comment: Try to use UrlAnnotation https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/UrlAnnotation