# Markwon linkify in a composable Text

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, linkify, markwon

In Android using jetpack-compose, is there currently a way to display a text containing links in a `@Composable Text`?

In legacy `TextView,` we used [Markwon](https://noties.io/Markwon/) with linkify plugin. Markwon creates a Spanned object that we can set into the `TextView`'s text.

Is there a way to proceed with the same with `@Composable Text`? Or do we have to use a legacy `TextView` embedded within a `@Composable AndroidView`?

Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66130513/linkify-with-compose-text and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65567412/jetpack-compose-text-hyperlink-some-section-of-the-text/65656351#65656351

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this library can help you:
https://github.com/jeziellago/compose-markdown

Add the repository to the project's build.gradle.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' } // add this
    }
}
```

Then, add the dependency to the module's build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.github.jeziellago:compose-markdown:0.2.0'
```

and finally, you can use the library as follows:

```
MarkdownText(
    markdown = "Click [here](http://www.google.com) or http://www.stackoverflow.com."
)
```

In this sample, both links are detected.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28842451)

Comment: @eldesgraciado edited for a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Still used the old Markwon and used the AndroidView Composeable to display an legacy TextView in my case, you can pass around a Spanned object and set on the TextView. The Linkify Plugin should work too